# Is $f(x)=o(x^\alpha)$ for every $\alpha\gt0$ enough to know that $\int_c^x dt/f(t) \sim x/f(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ be a monotone increasing function $[c,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$ satisfying $f(x)/x^\alpha\to 0$ for all $\alpha>0$.

> Is it true that $\int_c^x \frac{dt}{f(t)} \sim \frac{x}{f(x)}$ as $x\to \infty$?

This question is inspired by the fact that $\operatorname{li}(x)\sim x/\log x$. It seems to me that on heuristic grounds it should be true: in the case $f(t)=\log t$, what's going on is that $\log$ grows slow enough that it spends "most of the time" on the interval $[c,x]$ close to its value at the endpoint.  Thus $t/\log t$ is well-approximated by $t/\log x$ on "most of" the interval of integration.  The length of the interval is asymptotically $x$, and this is the explanation, morally anyway. Thus it should be that other functions that grow "slow enough" work the same way. And it seems to me (this is *extremely* unrigorous) that if $f(x)/x^\alpha\to 0,\forall \alpha>0$, that should be "slow enough", because

$$\int_c^x \frac{dt}{t^\alpha} = \frac{1}{1-\alpha}\cdot \frac{x}{x^\alpha} - \text{const.}$$

and $\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\to 1$ as $\alpha\to 0$. However, I have been unable to satisfy myself with a proper proof. The proof I know in the $f=\log$ case doesn't generalize because it involves the specifics of a particular integration by parts and involves facts like $\text{const.}/\log x\to 0$ that seem likely to be extrinsic to the result to me. Is there a proof that works in the generality in which I've posed the question? Or is it not actually true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider functions that are very close to step functions.  You could arrange it so that $x/f(x)$ grows approximately linearly to something like $x/\log x$, then decreases rapidly to something like $x/(\log x)^2$.  But your integral is an
increasing function of $x$...

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding the construction you're suggesting... if $x/f(x)$'s long-term behavior is like $x/(\log x)^2$, then it is increasing in the long term as well...?

Comment: No, $x/f(x)$ increases (with $f(x)$ almost constant) until it hits $x/(\log x)$, then $f(x)$ rises rapidly so $x/f(x)$ decreases rapidly to $x/(\log x)^2$.  Then repeat...

Comment: Oh, I wasn't clear that you wanted to repeat the whole thing...

Comment: Now that I get your idea, is not immediately clear to me that the increasing/decreasing of $x/f(x)$ is enough to rule out being $\sim$ to the (increasing) integral, without a little more argument about how widely it's swinging. It is possible for $f(x)\sim g(x)$ but $f$ is monotone and $g$ is not; take $f = x, g=x+\sin x \log x$. This is not swinging so wildly so it is intuitive to me that your case would rule out $\sim$ while this one doesn't, but can you do me the kindness of spelling out what else is needed?

Comment: Morally, though, I take your point. In the language of the question, we've got an $f$ that every so often changes very dramatically, so there is no reason to expect its value at a given $x$ to be "close to" its values on the bulk of the interval $[c,x]$, so the rationale underlying my conjecture is removed. I realize I would like to ask the same question with a convexity assumption on $x$.

Comment: Let $g(x)$ be your integral, and $h(x) = x/f(x)$.  For any $n > 0$ there are arbitrarily large $x_i$,  $y_i$ with $h(x_i) > n h(y_i) $, while $g(x_i) \le g(y_i)$.
So $\dfrac{h(x_i)}{g(x_i)} > n \dfrac{h(y_i)}{g(y_i)}$.

Comment: Thanks, yeah that does it.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is $C^1$ and
$$
\delta=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x\,f'(x)}{f(x)}\text{ exists and is }\ne1,
$$
then
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\int_c^x\frac{dx}{f(x)}}{\frac{x}{f(x)}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{f(x)}}{\frac{f(x)-x\,f'(x)}{f(x)^2}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{1-\frac{x\,f'(x)}{f(x)}}=\frac{1}{1-\delta}.
$$

Comment: Can you give me an example to show me that $f$ can satisfy both $\lim xf'/f =\delta >0$ and also $f/x^\alpha \to 0, \forall \alpha >0$? For example if $xf'/f=\delta>0$ then $f(x)=Cx^\delta$ which doesn't satisfy $f/x^\alpha\to 0$ if $\alpha\leq \delta$.

Comment: For the argument in my answer to work all you need is $f(x)/x\to0$ and $x\,f'(x)/x\to\delta\ne1$. It works for instance for $f(x)=(\log x)^r$, $r>0$ with $\delta=0$. If $\delta>0$ then it is easy to see that $f(x)\ge C\,x^\delta$.

Comment: If $\delta = 0$ then, by your argument, we have $\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\int_c^x dt/f(t)\right)/\left(x/f(x)\right) = 1/(1-0)=1$, so that $\int_c^x dt/f(t) \sim x/f(x)$ after all. I thought you were proposing a counterexample, did I misunderstand?

Comment: I guess actually you were giving a general theorem of which $\operatorname{li}(x)\sim x/\log x$ is an instance?

Comment: That's what I intended, to give a new proof for $\log x$ and for other functions like $(\log x)(\log\log x)$.